# Android Camera Driver

Tags: embedded, driver, android-camera

I am a newbie to android driver programming. I would like to write a camera driver for an embedded device. Can anyone tell me how to proceed and give me references to it.

Comment: To paraphrase - I have been given a bucket and spade for my birthday and I wanted to start by making something small and simple, please tell me how to build a full size replica of the Taj Mahal or the Empire State building.

Answer (score 1):

A [quick google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=android%20driver%20programming) lead me to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070159/how-to-start-android-kernel-programming) on SO. You're not going to get started on this at SO, you need to do more research so that you can start asking *specific* questions.