# Flow from Device driver to AOSP for BBB

Tags: android, kernel, android-source, beagleboneblack, hal

Is there any guidance available to start working with data manipulation from Linux kernel based device driver to Android HAL to AOSP source for Beagle-bone Black ?

I.e Hello world string reverse Linux driver getting accessed from Android app which all the way goes to Android App from native JNI api,services,HAL,Kernel.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Requests for tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: can you explain what is this then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070159/how-to-start-android-kernel-programming ?

Comment: Is there anyone who can guide ?